# Passing a pointer to a structure behaves differently in two programs

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, stack, function-pointers

I'm kind of confused right now. 
I have written two C programs. Below are the links

Please find the links in the comment below.

The first program is a implementation of stack using linked list. Meaning the insertion and deletion of nodes happens at top. ( LIFO principle ). 
The second program is a implementation of plane linked list. The nodes can be inserted at any position including the 0th position.

Here is my doubt where I need clarity.
Line 27 of the first link, breaks. It does not work. After some analysis, I got to know that I am not using a pointer to pointer. The head pointer on line 27 does not link to the newNode pointer the moment the control comes out of the insert function. (please spend some time on program to understand these pointers).

But, if this is the case, 
In program 2, Line 46 it works perfectly fine. And let me remind you I am not using pointer to a pointer here. It is just like previous program.
I am kind of really frustrated to feel how the actual concepts work.

As you can see the output of first program, is just 10. As the LinkedList breaks after the first node. 
And the output of second program is 13, 15, 45. The linked list does not break here at all, 
I really need somebody to help me out here. 
TIA

```
This is program 2.  Please find the first programs link in comment below.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// defining structure for a single node
typedef struct sllist
{
    int data;
    struct sllist *next;
}
sllnode;

// initially creating the first node of the Singly Linked List
void create(sllnode *head, int elem)
{
    head -> data = elem;
    head -> next = NULL;
}

// inserting a node
void insert( sllnode *head, int elem, int position )
{
    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        printf("NULL returned \n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // this overrides the very first node created through create() function
    if( position == 0 )
    {
        head -> data = elem;
        head -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        sllnode *temp = head;
        for ( int i = 0; i < position - 1; ++i )
        {
            temp = temp -> next;
        }

        sllnode *new_node = malloc( sizeof(sllnode) );
        new_node -> data = elem;
        new_node -> next = NULL;

        temp -> next = new_node; //this is working here, unlike the previous program I have shared. Why is this?
        // temp = new_node; // this code is just like previous code, this breaks again
    }
}

// print the entire linked list
void display(sllnode *head)
{
    sllnode *temp = head;
    while( temp != NULL )
    {
        printf("%d \n", temp -> data);
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
}

// main function
int main(void)
{
    sllnode *head = malloc( sizeof(sllnode) );
    create(head, 23);
    insert(head, 13, 0);
    insert(head, 15, 1);
    insert(head, 45, 2);
    display(head);
}
```

Comment: Program 1:  https://ideone.com/GdvHKl

    Program 2:  https://ideone.com/OL2LNl

Comment: Why do you think that two different programs should behave the same? Debug it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  In first program on line 27,  head = newNode; I am trying to make the head to point to newNode. Once the control is out of the insert function the head is pointing to its original node. I mean as newNode is a local variable aka local pointer, I believe the changes are not visible outside the scope of insert function in program 1.           If you see the same on line 46 of program 2, the changes are still reflecting unlike previous case

Comment: `if( position == 0 ) { head -> data = elem; head -> next = NULL;  }` This clearly kills your previous `head` instead of inserting anything into the list.

Comment: "I got to know that I am not using a pointer to pointer" -- that's the problem right there.

Answer (score 1):

This happens *all the time*.

Program 2 works because you pass in a pointer to an object and then you make changes to field within the object pointed to by your pointer (you assign to `head->data`).

Program 1 fails because you pass in a pointer to an object and then you change the pointer variable itself (you assign directly to `head`).

Everyone makes this mistake at some point.

In C, like many other languages, parameters are copies of their arguments. If you change the value of the parameter variable, it does not affect the argument (your problem in program #1). However, even though the pointer argument and pointer parameter are different pointers, they point to the same object, so if you modify the referent object through the parameter, the change can be seen through the argument after you return (which is why problem #2 works).

Draw pictures of the execution. It will become clear after doing so. The self-study is very worthwhile.

Comment: So, if I pass in a pointer to an object and if I wanna change this original pointer to point to some other location ( i.e changing the pointer variable itself) here comes the problem. For this I may have to use two things return or a pointer to pointer.  Is this correct ?                                                                  And If I just make changes to fields within the object like head -> data =10; or head -> next = newNode; Its completely fine because I am not changing the original pointer? And as the nature of pointers point to one location the changes get affected aftermath?

Comment: In this case _passing_ a pointer to a pointer is the way to do it, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes I believe that makes sense. Your answer was helpful to me. I was looking for a answer of this kind. Thanks !

Comment: No problem. Another thing you can do that might be easier to to make the stack be an struct which contains the head pointer as a field. Then you have `void push(stack* s) { ... s->head = ...}`

Comment: Sure ! @Ray Toal